# how to show a new user on the page?

Tags: reactjs

I'm a Junior. I could not find information on the Internet and could not solve it myself. I use for my app the react with axios. Through the post request I want to add a new user. How to show a new user on the page? not in the console.

```
import React from "react"; import axios from "axios";

class PersonInput extends React.Component {
  state = {
    name: '',

  }
  handleChange = (event) => {
      this.setState({name: event.target.value});
  }
  handleSubmit = (event) => {
      event.preventDefault();

      const user = {
          name: this.state.name
      };

    axios.post(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`, {user}).then((res) => {
      console.log(res);

    })
}

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <label>
            User Name:
            <input type="text" name="name" onChange={this.handleChange} />
          </label>
          <button type="submit">Add user</button>
          <ul>{this.state.res}</ul>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default PersonInput;
```

Comment: Well what is the design of your application? Where do the users go? is this a registration page that you are then taking the user to a home page or something? or do you just want to show user information in this existing class ?

Comment: Yes, I just want to show users. Add edit and so on.

Comment: well, then you probably want to add a `users` key to your state, store information about the user and then render on the component. I'd recommend something like Redux for state management so its not just local state on a component. Also you shouldn't be making the request in your component. If you navigate away from this page while creating a user for instance.. You can have an issue where setState is called on an unmounted component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't need to make a post request for it.
Try this:

```
import React from "react"; import axios from "axios";

class PersonInput extends React.Component {
  state = {
    name: '',
    users: ''

  }
  handleChange = (event) => {
      this.setState({name: event.target.value});
  }
  handleSubmit = (event) => {
      event.preventDefault();
      this.setState({users: this.state.name});
}

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <label>
            User Name:
            <input type="text" name="name" onChange={this.handleChange} />
          </label>
          <button type="submit">Add user</button>
          <ul>{this.state.users}</ul>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default PersonInput;
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a new key to your state and when u get response store it in that key

```js
state = {
  name: '',
  res: []
}

onSubmit = async e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const data = { name: this.state.name };

  const response = await axios.post('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users', data);
  this.setState({res: response.data});
}
```

And use async await it is easier and cleaner. Just a personal preference